# Magento 2 installation stuck at 71%

Tags: magento2.2

Magento 2 installation stuck at 71%

I installed many times but still installation stuck at 71%...have some one help me?

```
Current PHP version:  7.1
allow_url_fopen On
date.timezone UTC
display_errors Off
error_reporting E_ALL
file_uploads On
include_path .:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear
log_errors On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value
max_execution_time 18000
max_input_time -1
max_input_vars 8000
memory_limit 768M
open_basedir no value
post_max_size 128M
session.save_path /tmp
short_open_tag On
upload_max_filesize 1G
```

Comment: How you install Magento2, from the browser?

Comment: I confirm the same situation with sample pack, installation from browser. Your php values are very good. Initially I had to increase memory_limit and max_execution_time to your values. There are no errors in server log. The solution I found was to uninstall the version using command "php bin/magento setup:uninstall", then deleting all files from /var folder. I kept the database as it was. You can install it again, if it is stucked reload the page and finally the process completes 100%. Some people recommended changes in MySQL configuration file. I am on Debian 8, PHP 7.0, Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Wishlist sample data is wrong in the enterprise version, you can wait about 10mins, and then close the tab and directly open the frontend & backend, the installation had been succeed. (but missing some wishlist data)